# How to redirect a FOR command in Windows batch

Tags: batch-file

I know how to redirect a Windows shell command with the `>|>>|<|<<` operators, but I cannot accomplish it for commands used inside a `FOR` command?

For instance:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%I in (`__COMMAND__ 2>nul`) do (
    set MYVAR=%%I
)
```

You see, here I would like to silent the stderr of this `__COMMAND__`.
The shell complaints that it does not expect a `2` in that place (same behaviour for other redirections).

Anybody can help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%I in (`__COMMAND__ 2^>nul`) do (
    set MYVAR=%%I
)
```

[in this case](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) redirection and conditional execution operators need to be escaped with caret.

Or put everything in double quotes :

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%I in (`"__COMMAND__ 2>nul"`) do (
    set MYVAR=%%I
)
```

Using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is also possible:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "command=__COMMAND__ 2>nul"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%I in (`!command!`) do (
    set MYVAR=%%I
)
```

Comment: It works! This will probably be the most exhaustive answer ever possible for this stupid question so I'll accept it now. Thanks @npocmaka!